# Android Eclipse project properties error

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm really having some problems with Eclipse and Android SDK, I have been working on a project, and I opened it and I got an error staying about the project.properties, I used the android tools -> Fix project properties and I still got the project properties. So I removed the project from the workspace folder, I then moved it to my desktop and then imported to Eclipse, I now get this.

Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar'.    styles.xml  /Ball-O/res/values-v14  line 8  Android AAPT Problem
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Holo.Light'.  styles.xml  /Ball-O/res/values-v11  line 7  Android AAPT Problem

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Canvas

Update

I'm getting this error now

Project has no project.properties file!

Comment: Doesn't a reference to a resource need to be preceded with a @ symbol? Could that be your error with referencing the theme?

Comment: Well i don't need the theme so I removed them, and still i get the project has no project.properties file when it does

Comment: Using the Fix Project Properties didn't resolve the issue?

Comment: What i did was remove the project properties and just copy one from another project and it works fine now :)

Comment: That was going to be my suggestion to you.